# How to setup php to run from a single location in Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php

I've been struggling with this for some time now. I want to setup a Wordpress blog to run from a "/blogname" path on a server instead of the root. I also want the path to have a different name then the directory where the Wordpress scripts are since the server itself will run django.

I have Nginx as a reverse proxy and I set up php-fpm to run the wordpress. Here's my Nginx configuration file:

```
http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    #tcp_nopush         on;
    #gzip               on;

    server {
        root         /Users/username/Dev/Wordpress/;
        index        index.php index.html index.htm;
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        # Do not serve hidden files
        location ~ /\. {
            access_log      off; 
            log_not_found   off; 
            deny            all; 
        }

        # Static files
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

        # This is the problem
        location /blogname {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            rewrite  /blogname(.*) /blog$1 last;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/username/Dev/Wordpress/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now when I visit localhost:8080/blogname I just download the index.php script instead of executing it.

Other tips are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
location /blogname {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  rewrite  /blogname(.*) /blog$1 last;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  include       fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/username/Dev/Wordpress/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

with this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files                 $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass              127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index             index.php;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
  fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include                   fastcgi.conf;
}
```

I hope this should work for you because this is what I use for my local server.